# Requiring one of two fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm wondering if with the jquery validation plugin you can make 1 of 2 fields required.

I've looked through the docs but can't find anything to tell me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validation - Two fields, only required to fill in one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137844/jquery-validation-two-fields-only-required-to-fill-in-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If either one is needed `if(f1 || f2)` works.

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/VXuCr/

```
function validator () {
    var inputs = $('input');
    var f1 = inputs.eq(0).val();
    var f2 = inputs.eq(1).val();

    if( f1 || f2 ){        
      $("#message").html("OK");    
    }    
    else{
      $("#message").html("*fill at least one field");            
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the `required(dependency-callback)`

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-callback

And your `required` would be

```
required: function(element) {
    return $("#whatever").val() == "";
```

Or something like that.