# jQuery Validation - Two fields, only required to fill in one

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) on my form. On my form I have a 'Telephone' field and a 'Mobile No.' field.

How would I go about making it so the user has to fill in one of them, but it can be either field?

Comment: I think you'd have to find a way to remove a rule after one is filled in, and back again if they remove the value, and type in the second field. That would dynamically create your validation script. It sounds like a simple solution like this would work with simple jQuery, and not the validation library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate - require at least one field in a group to be filled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300994/jquery-validate-require-at-least-one-field-in-a-group-to-be-filled)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This looks like what you need to use [dependency-callback](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/)

What this will allow you to do is:

> Makes the element required, depending on the result of the given callback.

You can then place a `required` validation rule on the two telephone fields that will only be required based on the return from the function callback; thus you can put a rule on the telephone field to say require this rule only if the mobile field is blank, and vice versa for the mobile field.

This is untested but in theory

```
rules: {
    telephone: {
        required: function(element) {
            return $("#mobile").is(':empty');
        }
    },
    mobile: {
        required: function(element) {
            return $("#telephone").is(':empty');
        }
    }
}
```

**Be sure to check comments/other answers for possible updated answers.**

**UPDATE**

```
rules: {
     telephone: {
          required: '#mobile:blank'
     },
     mobile: {
          required: '#telephone:blank'
     }
}
```

Comment: There is (now) a simpler way of doing this: `required: "#mobile:empty"`

Comment: I have a similar requirement except that I need only one general message to show up at the top (or bottom) of the form as opposed to an error message next to each field in the form. In the quoted example, if both fields are empty, I will see the same error message next to each field which is redundant. At least for my situation, I need something like "At least one field must be filled." at the top of the form.

Comment: There's a problem with using this on textarea elements.  `:empty` will be true for a textarea.  In general, `:empty` is bad to use for validation, you should seek alternatives.

Comment: @Milimetric : Agree.  Try using `:filled` or `:blank` as per documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/.

Comment: There is no need anymore to use another plugin, please see the other answers. BTW: the link is dead.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was able to solve my issue by compiling all answers from jeff-wilbert, saluce and @cartbeforehorse . Be nice of the answer could be updated to reflect those updates.

Answer (score 51):

I think that the correct way of do this is using the "require_from_group" method.

You can checkit on http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/

The example is exactly what your are searching for:

```
<input class="left phone-group" id="mobile_phone" name="mobile_phone">
<input class="left phone-group" id="home_phone" name="home_phone">
<input class="left phone-group" id="work_phone" name="work_phone">

<script>
$( "#form" ).validate({
  rules: {
    mobile_phone: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
    },
    home_phone: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
    },
    work_phone: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

It's mandatory to include additional-methods.js

Comment: This method works better. The message is clearer and the errors are clean up as soon as you type inside one the grouped fields. Notice you need to include additional-methods.js

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! It is part of the api and easiest to use.

Comment: Voted up as the accepted answer as this is the most helpful and uses the plugin's built in feature rather than a reinvented wheel solution.

Comment: @PhilCook Just a little FYI even though this is like 6 months from your posts... when using SO and leaving comments like these saying something should be the "accepted" answer should be worded more so like "as of YYYY-MM-DD this would be the correct way to handle this situation based on the current api documentation".  You have to realize the original question is almost 4 years prior to when this answer was posted and more then likely a lot has changed since then in the way to handle certain situations.

Comment: This one worked perfectly for me. Do not forget to include `additional-methods.min.js` or you will get an error

Answer (score 30):

Came here looking for the same answers.  Found the above post very helpful. Thanks.

I have extended this solution to check if the other field is in fact valid, rather than just "not empty".  This ensures that the user inputs a valid Phone Number before removing the "required" class from the Mobile field and vice versa.

```
Mobile: {
    required: function(element) {
    return (!$("#Phone").hasClass('valid'));
    }
},
Phone: {
    required: function(element) {
        return (!$("#Mobile").hasClass('valid'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, IMO. The others just didn't work for me.

Comment: I found issue with the solution if you already enter valid input, and then remove than the html element will still have class "valid" and not rerun validation again. I think its better to use require_from_group, as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had troubles is `.is(':empty')` so here is my working options example.

Before:

```
rules: {
   name:       {required: true},
   email:      {required: true},
   phone:      {required: true}
}
```

All fields *were* required. But I wanted email and/or phone so to create the 'or':

```
rules: {
   name:       {required: true},
   email:      {required: 
                    function() {
                        //returns true if phone is empty   
                        return !$("#phone").val();
                    }
               },
   phone:      {required:
                    function() {
                        //returns true if email is empty
                        return !$("#email").val();
                     }
               }
},
messages: {
   email: "Email is required if no phone number is given.",
   phone: "A phone number is required if no phone email is given."
}
```

And you will see that I've added the `messages` option to give the user some meaningful info because the default messages would say that each field is required which is not true in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Requirement is Validation need to be either C or (A and B) is required. 
The thing worked for me is:

```
$.validator.addMethod("multipeFieldValidator", function(value) { 
    var returnVal = false; 
    if($("#Cfield").val() != '' || ($("#Afield").val() != '' && $("#Bfield").val() != '')) {
        returnVal = true;
    }
    return returnVal; 
}, 'Either C or A and B is required');


$('#Afield.form-control').change(function(){
    $(this).valid();
    $("#Bfield").valid();
    $("#Cfield").valid();

});

$('#Bfield.form-control').change(function(){
    $(this).valid();
    $("#Afield").valid();
    $("#Cfield").valid();
});

$('#Cfield.form-control').change(function(){
    $(this).valid();
    $("#Bfield").valid();
    $("#Afield").valid();
});


within rules I have 
Afield: "multipeFieldValidator",
Bfield: "multipeFieldValidator",
Cfield: "multipeFieldValidator"
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("mobile10d", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid 10 digit phone number.");
    $("#form_id").validate({
        rules: {
            mobile: {
                required: "#telephone:blank",
                mobile10d: true
            },
            telephone: {
                required: "#mobile:blank",
                mobile10d: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form class="" action="" method="POST" id="form_id">
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label class="form-control">Mobile<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="0-9">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label class="form-control">Telephone<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="0-9">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" class="apply-now-btn">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Some explanation might be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

This Will do

```
Mobile: {
    required: function(element) {
    return (jQuery.isEmptyObject($("#Phone").val()));
    }
},
Phone: {
    required: function(element) {
        return (jQuery.isEmptyObject($("#Mobile").val()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought this might be a helpful addition - no plugin needed.
This will handle all input fields inside a div when only one is required.
You can alter it to your needs - like creating extra validation on the found inputs.

**THE HTML**

```
<div class="MOTHER-DIV">
    -- any content can go here
    -- all inputs will be checked
    -- returns true on one value found
</div>
```

**THE CODE**

```
var hasInput=false;
$(".MOTHER-DIV :input").each(function () {
    if($(this).val()  !== "") {
        hasInput=true;
    }
});
if(!hasInput) {
    alert("nothing found");
} else {
    alert("content found");
}
```

**For checkboxes, use:**

```
var hasCheckBoxInput=false;
$('.OTHER-DIV input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        hasCheckBoxInput=true;
    }
});
if(!hasCheckBoxInput) {
    alert("NO checkbox is checked");
} else {
    alert("YES! One checkbox checked");
}
```