# jQuery Validate plugin : Only one field required out of multiple

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-validate

Wrt this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137844/jquery-validation-two-fields-only-required-to-fill-in-one) , if the telephone and mobile fields are empty then it gives an error message but after that when either of the two is filled and the form is submittted again then too the error message remains . The validation check takes place with the old value of the input and when the page is refreshed then it takes new values. I will be grateful if anyone can help me fixing this problem ??

Comment: Please show your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)  As per [the question you've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137844/jquery-validation-two-fields-only-required-to-fill-in-one), I constructed [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hUsjg/) using [the `depends` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) and still see lots of issues.  The rules do not seem to work at all, where both fields are always required.

2)  There is a `require_from_group` rule included in the `additional-methods.js` file.  The two fields must have the same `class` for the rule to target, in this case, `.group`.   But this method [has some known bugs](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412) where it disables all of the other rules on the form

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/SvSrR/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        groups: {
            name: "telephone mobile"
        },
        rules: {
            telephone: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.group']
            },
            mobile: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.group']
            }
        }
    });

});
```

---

3)  Instead, I constructed a custom rule called `customrule` (you can name it however you want) and it's working as I believe it should.  I also used the `groups` option to combine the two error messages into one.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2g8hL/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("customrule", function (value, element) {
        return (!($("#mobile").val() === '') || !($("#telephone").val() === ''));
    }, "please fill out at least one");

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        groups: {
            name: "telephone mobile"
        },
        rules: {
            telephone: {
                customrule: true
            },
            mobile: {
                customrule: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate solution . Actually I am using ruby on rails . The solution you gave seems to work well with normal HTML forms but the same problem of validator taking old values persists when using rails forms.

Comment: It works with rails forms too...i guess there is some other issue with my code....

Comment: @user1484793, it would really help if you edited your OP to show the rendered HTML code of you form, as well as your jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try to put custom error placement

```
$('#form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
                       return true;
                    }
});
```

Comment: What does error placement have to do with making "one field in a group" required?