# Pop up errors for a group in jquery validation

Tags: jquery-validate, alert

I am using jQuery validation plugin for form validation .The form has a group of entries out of which only one needs to be filled . For this I used the logic in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293332/jquery-validate-plugin-only-one-field-required-out-of-multiple). I want my errors to be displayed as pop ups and for the group only one pop up to be displayed. For error display I am using errorPlacement .
Here is my code for errorPlacement :

```
errorPlacement : function(error,element) {
 if (element.attr("name") == "telephone" || element.attr("name") == "mobile")
    alert(error.html);
 }
```

The problem is that this pops up two different messages one while validating mobile and another while validating telephone. How can I modify my code to pop up only once.

Comment: Do not use an `alert()` for this.  You're using jQuery so you might as well use some nice tooltip popups.

Comment: I can use jquery dialog but am not sure how to use it here . I want to avoid using jquery plugins. Plz give me a pointer how to do this.

Comment: I found a crude solution for this. Declared a variable count=0 , and checked for count%2 ==0 and if true called the alert !!!

Comment: Please delete your own question if you've solved this.  Otherwise, post detailed instructions below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did so that pop up pops up only once :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.validator.addMethod("customrule", function (value, element) {
    return (!($("#mobile").val() === '') || !($("#telephone").val() === ''));
}, "please fill out at least one");
var count =0;
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    groups: {
        name: "telephone mobile"
    },
    rules: {
        telephone: {
            customrule: true
        },
        mobile: {
            customrule: true
        }
    },
   errorPlacement : function(error,element) {
       if (element.attr("name") == "telephone" || element.attr("name") == "mobile")
          if (count%2 ==0)
           alert(error.html());
          count++;
     }
 });

});
```