# jQuery validate dependancy call function

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

The following jQuery validate code is supposed to check the form that the user must enter the e_usage field if the e_usagelow field has not been filled in. I wrote the dependency call function for e-usage based on the example at [jQuery Validation - Two fields, only required to fill in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137844/jquery-validation-two-fields-only-required-to-fill-in-one), but somehow my function doesnt work (e.g. when putting the mouse on the e-usage field while e_usagelow is empty no validation-error warning appears and the console shows the value 'true')

What goes wrong?

Please your help.

html code:

```
E-usage: <input id="e_usage" type="text" name="e_usage">
E-usage low: <input id="e_usagelow" type="text" name="e_usagelow" >
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
      'e_usage': {
        required: function (element) {
          console.log("validation: required: " + $("#e_usagelow").is(':empty'));
          return $("#e_usagelow").is(':empty');
        },
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 8,
        number: true
      },
      'e_usagelow': {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 8,
        number: true
      }
    } //rules
  }); //validate()
}); //function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/PyMCx/)

change `'e_usage'` to `e_usage`

and `'e_usagelow'` to `e_usagelow`

`id` is not enclosed in quotes

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myForm").validate({

        rules: {
            e_usage: { //removed quotes from id
                required: function (element) {
                    console.log("validation: required: " + $("#e_usagelow").is(':empty'));
                    return $("#e_usagelow").is(':empty');
                },
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 8,
                number: true
            },

            e_usagelow: { //removed quotes from id
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 8,
                number: true
            }

        } //rules


    }); //validate()

});
```

Comment: thnx for the swift response. Unfortenately it still doesnt work unless I have a different/wrong expectation about the validation function. (After applying your suggested change:) When I as a user perform the following steps:(1) fill in only 1 char in 'e_usage' field -> error warning; (2) delete char in e_usage field -> error warning "this field is required"';(3) fill in 4 chars in 'e_usagelow' field -> error warning "this field is required" at e_usage field does NOT disappear (??) what I would have expected...

Comment: UPDATE: seems that the is(':empty') function does not work (not sure why not???). $("#e_usagelow").val().length (>0 comparison) seems to work

Comment: @user2543182 `is(':empty')` not working use `return ($("#e_usagelow").val().length > 0)?false:true;` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/PyMCx/1/)

Comment: @Tushar, the quotation marks around the name are optional.  If the name contains dots or brackets, quotes are mandatory.  In other words, putting quotes around the name is never an issue.

Comment: thnx for all comments(!), works now. @Sparky: agree, with quotes worked for me before as well...