# jQuery Conditional Validation on textarea and file inputs

Tags: jquery, html, validation, conditional-statements

I have a modal popup with a form, I can setup the basic validation code however I am unsure how to go about what I need.

I have 2 inputs a `<textarea>` and a `<input type="file">`for image uploads.
I would like to check that at least one of them is valid.
an example would be...

1) user adds description into the text area but no image `//this is fine and file upload not required`

2) user adds file but not description `//this is fine and textarea not required`

3) user adds neither and is prompted to fill in one of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to do something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/jaumzera/erpvfdhf/2/

Comment: Yes exactly but preferably using jQuery validate

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1o04ro4m/) exemplifying some simple logic behind your problem.

```
$('#validate').click(function(){
    var text = false;
    var file = false;

    if ( $('textarea').val() != '' )
        text = true;

    if ( $('input').val() != '' )
        file = true;

    if ( !text && !file )
        alert ('Woah! Enter one of those!');
    else
        alert('I can live with one input');

});
```

On `click` or `submit` or whatever event you choose, take a look at the value of the textarea and the file input. If the value is false, you know that field is "invalid." If you find that both fields are "invalid" then you prompt your user to enter one of them. Otherwise, you have "valid" input and can move on to other actions.

Just be sure to use the proper selectors to apply to your code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="text" />
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="ok" id="ok" />
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $("#ok").click(function() {
    var $text = $("#text");
    var $textarea = $("#textarea");
    if ($text.val() == "" && $textarea.val() == "") {
      alert("fill at least one");
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the complete fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/erpvfdhf/3/

There's also an example using jQuery Validator here: [jQuery Validation - Two fields, only required to fill in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137844/jquery-validation-two-fields-only-required-to-fill-in-one)