# Jquery.Validate - Add / Remove Rules based on which tab

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-validate

I have a Bootstrap 4 tabbed interface with input boxes on each tab.  I want to allow the user to input different Required fields based on which tab they are on, therefore I wish to add or remove validation based on that tab.  There are also a few input that are mandatory, no mater what tab the user is in.

What I have done is create a Default Validation function that adds the 2 shared inputs and their rules.  I then us the Bootstrap events to capture which tab is clicked, removed any existing validation and create validation for that specific tab.

I have 90% of this working, though I've recently noticed that the inputs inside the tab do not actually get reset when tabbing back and forth.  I have attempted to use addmethod but simply never got the new rules to function.

My Real life app has more than 2 Tabs so i also cannot simply toggle back and forth between on 2 sets of rules.

Fiddler [here](https://jsfiddle.net/timcadieux/9wg3sbqn/76/)

```
var currTab = '#tab1';
ValidationDefaults();
Tab1Validation();


$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  currTab = $(e.target).attr("href"); // activated tab

  ClearValidation();
  ValidationDefaults();

});

$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(e) {

  switch (currTab) {
    case "#tab1":

      Tab1Validation();
      break;
    case "#tab2":

      Tab2Validation();
      break;
  }

  if ($("form").valid()) {

  }
});


function Tab1Validation() {

  //https://stackoverflow.com/a/28954059/1555453
  var validator = $("#Create").validate({
    rules: {
      username: {
        require_from_group: [1, ".Tab1Group"]
      },
      username2: {
        require_from_group: [1, ".Tab1Group"]
      }
    },
    messages: {
      username: "* You must enter either a username or a Username 2",
      username2: "* You must enter either a username or a Username 2"
    }
  });

}

function Tab2Validation() {

  //https://stackoverflow.com/a/28954059/1555453
  var validator = $("#Create").validate({
    rules: {
      street: {
        required: true
      },
      city: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      street: "* You must enter either a street",
      city: "* You must enter either a city"
    }
  });

}

function ClearValidation() {
  var validator = $("#Create").validate();
  validator.resetForm();

  $('#Create').removeData('validator');
  ValidationDefaults();
}

function ValidationDefaults() {

  $.validator.setDefaults({
    rules: {
      firstname: {
        required: true
      },
      lastname: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      firstname: "* A first name is Required",
      lastname: "* A last name is Required"
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
      element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is the wrong approach...

The `.validate()` method can only be called ***once*** for initializing the plugin on your form, and since all subsequent calls would be ignored, it cannot be called multiple times to re-write your rules.

The proper way to handle all of this would be to:

1. Call `.validate()` once on page load and then
2. call the `.rules('add')` and `.rules('remove')` methods to dynamically toggle your rules as needed.

Try something like this:  [jsfiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c6sx3mhq/)

```
var currTab = '#tab1'
ValidationDefaults();  // INITIALIZE PLUGIN ON FORM
Tab1Validation();      // SETUP TAB 1 with RULES

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    currTab = $(e.target).attr("href"); // activated tab
});

$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
    switch (currTab) {
        case "#tab1":
            Tab1Validation();
            break;
        case "#tab2":
            Tab2Validation();
            break;
    }
    if ($("form").valid()) {

    }
});

function Tab1Validation() {
    // ADD RULES FOR TAB 1
    $('#tab1 input').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            require_from_group: [1, ".Tab1Group"],
            messages: {
                require_from_group: "* You must enter either username or username2"
            }
        });
    });
    // REMOVE RULES FOR TAB 2
    $('#tab2 input').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('remove');
    });
}

function Tab2Validation() {
    // ADD RULES FOR TAB 2
    $('#tab2 input').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
        });
    });
    // REMOVE RULES FOR TAB 1
    $('#tab1 input').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('remove');
    });
}

function ValidationDefaults() {
    // INITIALIZE PLUGIN ON PAGE LOAD
    $('#Create').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "* A first name is Required",
            lastname: "* A last name is Required"
        },
        // combine messages into one for "require_from_group"
        groups: {  
            tab1: "username username2"
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
            element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
        },
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
        }
    });
}
```

Note that I used a jQuery `.each()` to apply all the rules at once to all the fields within a tab.  If you need to apply unique rules/messages to the individual fields then remove the `.each()` and attach `.rules()` to single field selectors as needed.